# Can anyone explain Lazy loading in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want a simple explanation about Lazy loading in Entity Framework with a simple example.

- Why do we use Lazy loading?
- When do we use Lazy loading?

Comment: http://entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx#.USs7CB3ql0U

Comment: Read the Exam 70-516 training material

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is probably a little unspecific for an SO question, which tend to be about precise issues with definite solutions, so I'm afraid it'll get closed as "Not Constructive". To see how to get the best from SO, please check out the [About], [FAQ] and [ask] pages.

Answer (score 3):

Lazy loading means delaying the loading of related data until you specifically request it.

take an example from here..

[Lazy loading](http://entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx#.USs64KVBNiM)

Comment: i was about to write exactly the same answer.

Comment: @AbiRuban - then please start a different question for that. It is not relevant to this question

Comment: Thread is also "delaying the loading" then why we use Lazy loading